# Simulink is to Matlab as _______ is to Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, mathematica

What is the Mathematica equivalent of Matlab's Simulink?  I want something that lets me build a discrete event simulation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent product for *Mathematica* is the [SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) (also see the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_SystemModeler)).

Comment: +1 You hardly ever see any perfect 1 word answers.  Excellent!

Comment: He's indeed very right, but I wouldn't link to the wikipedia page if there is a regular site with much more info. Still +1

Comment: I chose to link to the Wikipedia page because I thought it did a better job of explaining how MathModelica could be integrated with Mathematica, but I'm fine with the edit.